# How to list todays files only in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need a simple command that would allow me to turn in a list of file names that have been generated during the day. Something a could just pipe to awk so I can generate a list file that would contain the day of creation and name.
(something like)

xx/xx/xx   foo_0020.bin

xx/xx/xx   Guacamole_0004.txt

xx/xx/xx   etc...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got just what you might be looking for:

ls -lR --time-style=+%D | grep `date +%D`

You can then pipe the output to awk like:

ls -lR --time-style=+%D | grep `date +%D` | awk '{print $6"\t" $7}'

Answer (score 2):

I would use [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

```
find . -type f -mtime -1 -exec ls -lR --time-style=+%D {} \; | awk '{print $6, $7}'
```

Comment: I had not considered including the path of the filename, Nice one, Thks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
ls -l | grep "`date +%b" "%d`" | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on exactly what you need it for. If you need a list of all files that were modified/created in the last 24 hours, find will do it for you:

```
find . -mtime -1
```